# AngularJS form input with Google Places API not saving full string

Tags: angularjs, forms, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am trying to capture data from a form input that utilizes the Google Places API.

If I begin typing a location like for instance "***Kingst***", and I then choose "***Kingston ON, Canada***" from the drop-down list of related suggestions, the input field populates with "***Kingston ON, Canada***" as it should.

[image]

However, when I hit the save button, only what I originally typed is saved to the database. ie: "***Kingst***".

[image]

Here is a possible hint:
During multiple tests, I have found out that if I put my cursor back into that same input field and then remove it again, the proper full string is saved to the database when I hit the submit button.

I'm not sure how to get the full string to save upon selecting a suggestion from the dropdown, without having to put my cursor into the field and change the string.

In my form I have this input field:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="eventLocation" placeholder="Event Location..." class="form-control" name="eventLocation" ng-model="newEvent.location">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="hidden" id="eventLat" placeholder="Latitude..." class="form-control" name="eventLat" ng-model="newEvent.lat">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="hidden" id="eventLng" placeholder="Longitude..." class="form-control" name="eventLng" ng-model="newEvent.lng">
 <button type="submit" ng-disabled="fuck.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="addEvent(newEvent);newEvent = null;">send</button>
</form>
```

In the HTML below the form I have the following:

```
<script>
  // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
  // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
  // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

  var placeSearch, autocomplete;

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('eventLocation')),
      {types: ['geocode']});  

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInLatLng);
  }

  function fillInLatLng() {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    var lat = place.geometry.location.lat(),
    lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

    var eventLat = document.getElementById('eventLat');
    var eventLon = document.getElementById('eventLng');

    eventLat.value = lat;
    eventLon.value = lng;

        console.log(lat);
        console.log(lng);
  }

  // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
  </script>
```

In the controller I have:

```
 $scope.addEvent = function(newEvent) {
    var eventLat = document.getElementById('eventLat').value;
    var eventLng = document.getElementById('eventLng').value;

    if (newEvent) {
        // push a event to the end of the array
      $scope.events.$add({
        location:  newEvent.location,
        latitude:  eventLat,
        longitude: eventLng,
        createdBy: user.uid,
        createdAt: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
      })
      // display any errors
            .catch(alert);
    }
    document.getElementById('eventLat').value = '';
    document.getElementById('eventLng').value = '';
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by doing the following:

In my controller I added:

```
var eventLoc = document.getElementById('eventLocation').value;

...

$scope.events.$add({
   location:  eventLoc,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you used this code. Because while using this code circular to json conversion is build inside the js

Controller.js file

```
.directive('googleplace', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
            var options = {
                types: [],
                componentRestrictions: {country: 'in'}
            };
            scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);

            google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    model.$setViewValue(element.val());                
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Note:If u can read on specfic country means , include this tag

```
componentRestrictions: {country: 'in'}
```

In HTML file you just add googleplace tag only.